# Microsoft HPC not allowing cancelling jobs using REST interface

Tags: rest, hpc

I am having real trouble figuring out why I cannot cancel a job.
The command I run is:

```
  https://head_node_name:port/WindowsHPC/HPC_cluster_name/Job/job_identifier/Cancel
```

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh560253(v=vs.85).aspx 
The error I get is  *Service : Method not allowed*. I am running **Windows HPC 2008 R2 Service Pack 3**. My scheduler is configured as Queued,Graceful pre-emption, Adjust resources automatically, and 15sec task cancel grace period. I have administrator rights on the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you get 405 error (Method not allowed) in case of mismatch of the request method for desired resource (for example GET instead of POST).

Recommend using Chrome and installing an extension Simple REST Client which is an easy way to send GET/POST requests on the fly.